# Whitespace delimiter sep='\s+' not effectively working in Jupyter Notebook with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I ended up solving this right after I finished to question.

Reviewed Documentation for `pandas.read_csv`

```
delim_whitespace : boolean, default False

Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep. 
Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is set to True, nothing should be 
passed in for the delimiter parameter.
```

should show `sep='\\s+'`

---

Original question:

I get a warning that **delim_whitespace=True** is deprecated and to use **sep='\s+'**. However when I use **sep='\s+'** I get the error:

`SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\s'`

I similarly receive the same error when running in IDLE.

Code:

````
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/housing.data"
names = ['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']
dataframe = read_csv(url, sep='\s+', names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,0:13]
Y = array[:,13]
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=7, shuffle = True)
model = KNeighborsRegressor()
scoring = 'neg_mean_squared_error'
results = cross_val_score(model, X, Y, cv=kfold, scoring=scoring)
print(results.mean())```
````

Comment: use a raw string: `sep=r'\s+'`

Comment: @mozway Yeah I figured out how to do it (was in the middle of doing answer before it was closed). The problem is that the documentation gives a single backslash 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
Was trying to help others avoid the headache of figuring out that they didn't escape the backslash in the documentation